# Session variables from for not stored and accessible on other pages

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables

I hope I'm not asking a question already answered, I have searched extensively on the site for an answer to my problem but can not manage to find a solution.

I have the following problem.

I have a form in which is a shopping cart, it is supposed to apply a coupon and then save those values so they can be used later on different pages.

For some reason however, these session variables are not saved.

My form looks like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
     $cart_custom = json_decode($_COOKIE['view_cart_custom_fab'],true);
    //print_r($cart_custom);
    include_once("inc/header.php");
    //set_add_to_cart_cookie();
    $fetch_user_info = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st_customer` WHERE `email`= '{$_SESSION['USER_EMAIL']}'");
    $fetch_info = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_user_info);

    $size_id = ($_REQUEST['id'] ? $_REQUEST['id'] : $_COOKIE['fabric_size_id']);
    $fabric_id = $_COOKIE['fabric_id'];
    $fabric_back = $_COOKIE['fabric_back']; 
    $shirts = $_COOKIE['shirts'];
    $fabric_arms = $_COOKIE['fabric_arms'];
    $fabric_pocket = $_COOKIE['fabric_pocket'];
    $fabric_cuff = $_COOKIE['fabric_cuff'];
    $fabric_boy_border = $_COOKIE['fabric_boy_border']; 

    $fabric = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st-fabrics` where `id` = '$fabric_id'");
    $fabric_record = mysqli_fetch_array($fabric);
    $fabric_back_data = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st-fabrics` where `id` = '$fabric_back'");
    $fabric_back_record = mysqli_fetch_array($fabric_back_data);
    $arms = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st-fabrics` where `id` = '$fabric_arms'");
    $arms_record = mysqli_fetch_array($arms);
    $pocket = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st-fabrics` where `id` = '$fabric_pocket'");
    $pocket_record = mysqli_fetch_array($pocket);
    $cuff = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st-fabrics` where `id` = '$fabric_cuff'");
    $cuff_record = mysqli_fetch_array($cuff);
    $border = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st-fabrics` where `id` = '$fabric_boy_border'");
    $border_record = mysqli_fetch_array($border);
    $select_size = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st_sizes` where `size_id` = '$size_id'"); 
    $user_select_size = mysqli_fetch_array($select_size);
    $model_id = $user_select_size['size_model'];
    $model = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st_model` where `model_id` = '$model_id'"); 
    $model_name = mysqli_fetch_array($model);
    if($shirts=="half_shirt"){
        $shirt = $user_select_size['half_sleeve'];
    }
    if($shirts=="full_tshirt"){
        $shirt = $user_select_size['full_sleeve'];
    }
    $cm1 = $fabric_record['fabric_price']/10;
    $cm2 = $arms_record['fabric_price']/10;
    $cm3 = $fabric_back_record['fabric_price']/10;
    $front_size = ($cm1*$user_select_size['front']*100);
    $back_size = ($cm3*$user_select_size['size_back']*100);
    $arms_size = ($cm2*$shirt*100);

    $front_back_total = $user_select_size['front']+$user_select_size['size_back'];
    $custom_total = ($front_size+$back_size+$arms_size);

    if(isset($_POST['apply_coupon_btn'])){
        $query_coupon = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st_coupon` WHERE `coupon_code`='{$_POST['coupon_apply']}' AND `status`='1'");
        $fetch_coupon = mysqli_fetch_array($query_coupon);
        $message = "tmp2";
        if(isset($fetch_coupon)){
            $_SESSION['coupon_data'] = $fetch_coupon;
            $check_user_id = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st_order` as so JOIN `st_coupon` as sc on so.`coupon_id`=sc.`coupon_id`  WHERE sc.`coupon_code`='{$_POST['coupon_apply']}' AND so.`user_id`={$_SESSION['user_id']}");
            $message = "tmp3";
            if(mysqli_num_rows($check_user_id)){
                $message = "U hebt deze kortingscode reeds gebruikt";
            }else{
                if($fetch_coupon['coupon_type'] == "price"){
                    $_SESSION['price_coupon_price'] = $fetch_coupon['coupon_value'];
                    unset($_SESSION['price_coupon_percent']);
                }elseif($fetch_coupon['coupon_type'] == "percent"){
                    $_SESSION['price_coupon_percent'] = $fetch_coupon['coupon_value'];
                    unset($_SESSION['price_coupon_price']);
                }
            }
        }else{
            $message = "Foute kortingscode";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['remove_coupon_btn'])){
        unset($_SESSION['price_coupon_percent']);
        unset($_SESSION['price_coupon_price']);
        unset($_SESSION['coupon_data']);
        unset($_SESSION['price_coupon_value']);
        header("location: winkelwagen.php");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['update_cart']))
    {
        echo "update cart";
        foreach($_POST['custom_qty_cart'] as $key=>$qtys){
            $cart_custom[$key]['price']['qty'] = $qtys;
        }
        setcookie('view_cart_custom_fab', json_encode($cart_custom), time() + (86400 * 2), "/");
        setcookie('custom_qty', $_POST['custom_qty'], time() + (86400 * 2), "/");

        $custom_total = $custom_total*$_POST['custom_qty'];
        setcookie('custom', $custom_total, time() + (86400 * 2), "/");
        foreach($_POST["qty"] as $key => $qty) { //Print each item, quantity and price.
           $id = $_POST["product_id"][$key];
           $_SESSION["products"][$id]["fabric_qty"] = $qty;
        }
        header("location: winkelwagen.php");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['checkout_btn'])){
        if($_SESSION['USER_EMAIL']){
            header("location: afrekenen.php");
        }else{ 
            header("location: winkelwagen.php#login-modelbox");
        }
    }
?> 

<div class="container">
    <h4><?php echo $_SESSION['price_coupon_value']; ?></h4>
    <h4><?php echo $_SESSION['coupon_data']; ?></h4>
    <div class="main_content fabric-content margin_top">
        <?php

        ?>
        <?php if (!empty($_SESSION["products"]) || count($cart_custom) > 0) { ?>
        <form method="POST" action="winkelwagen.php" style="width:60%; float:left; position:relative; left: 50%;">
        <table class="margin_top" style="float: left; position: relative; left: -50%;">
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id" colspan="1" style="width: 15%;"></th>
                <th data-field="id" colspan="1" style="width: 35%;">Naam</th>
                <th data-field="id" colspan="1" style="width: 35%;">Aantal</th>
                <th data-field="id" colspan="1" style="width: 15%;">Prijs</th>
            </tr>
        <?php if(count($cart_custom) > 0){ ?>
            <?php
                $total_price = 0;
                foreach($cart_custom as $key=>$val){

                    $cookie_model = $cart_custom[$key]['model'];
                    $cookie_price = $cart_custom[$key]['price'];
                    $model_name = $cookie_model['model'];

                    if($model_name == "wranglan_model"){
                        $model_img = "image/t-shirt.png";
                    }elseif($model_name == "round_model"){
                        $model_img = "image/t-shirt.png";
                    }
                    $model_qty = str_replace(",",".",$cookie_price['qty']);
                    $model_price = $model_qty * $cookie_price['ttl_price'];
                    $total_price = $model_qty * $cookie_price['ttl_price'] + $total_price;
                    if(isset($_GET['remove_id'])){
                        unset($cart_custom[$_GET['remove_id']]);
                        setcookie('view_cart_custom_fab', json_encode($cart_custom), time() + (86400 * 2), "/");
                        header("location: winkelwagen.php");
                    }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='1' style="width: 15%;">
                    <img src='<?php echo $model_img; ?>' alt='' class='img_table responsive_img' />
                </td>
                <td colspan='1' style="width: 35%;">
                    T-shirt op smaak 
                </td>
                <td colspan='1' style="width: 35%;">
                    <input id='update_cart' name='update_cart' type='hidden' value='' />
                    <input class="qty" type="text" name="custom_qty_cart[<?php echo $key; ?>]" value="<?php echo $model_qty; ?>"  style="width: 20%; text-align:right;"/>
                    <input name='Update'  style="width: 18px; vertical-align:bottom" type='image' value='update_cart' src='/image/update.jpg' alt='Update' onclick = "return setHidden('update_cart');" />
                    <a href="?remove_id=<?php echo $key;?>" style="width: 18px; vertical-align:bottom"><img src="/image/recycle.jpg" style="width: 18px; vertical-align:bottom"></a>
                </td>
                <td colspan='1' style="width: 15%;">
                    <?php echo price_format($model_price); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if(!empty($_SESSION["products"])){?>
            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION["products"]) > 0) {
                $total = 0;
                $list_tax = '';

                foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $product) { //Print each item, quantity and price.
                    //print_r($_SESSION["products"]);
                    $product_name = $product["fabric_name"];
                    $product_id = $product["id"];
                    //$product_qty = ($product["fabric_qty"] > 1 ? $product["fabric_qty"]:1);
                    $product_qty = str_replace(",",".",$product["fabric_qty"]);
                    //$product_price = ($product_qty>1 ? $product["fabric_price"] * $product_qty : $product["fabric_price"]);
                    $product_price = ($product["fabric_price"] * $product_qty);
                    $product_code = $product["product_code"];
                    $product_color = $product["product_color"];
                    $product_size = $product["product_size"];
                    $item_price = $product_price;
                    $total_cost_price = $total_cost_price + $item_price;
                    //$item_price   = sprintf("%01.2f",($product_price * $product_qty));  // price x qty = total item price

                    if(isset($_GET['removeid'])){
                        unset($_SESSION["products"][$_GET['removeid']]);
                        header("location: winkelwagen.php");
                    }

                    $cart_box .= 
                        "<tr><td colspan='1' style='width: 15%'><img src='admin/images/fabric/" . $product['fabric_texture'] . "' alt='' class='img_table responsive_img' /></td>
                        <td  colspan='1' style='width: 35%'>$product_name</td>
                        <td  colspan='1' style='width: 35%'>
                            <input id='update_cart' name='update_cart' type='hidden' value='' />
                            <input type='text' name='qty[]'  class='qty' min='1' max='100' value='".$product_qty."' style='width: 20%; text-align:right;'/>
                        <input name='Update'  style='width: 18px; vertical-align:bottom' type='image' value='update_cart' src='/image/update.jpg' alt='Update' onclick = 'return setHidden('update_cart');' />
                            <a href='?removeid=$product_id' style='width: 18px; vertical-align:bottom'><img src='/image/recycle.jpg' style='width: 18px; vertical-align:bottom'></a>
                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id[]' value='".$product_id."' /></td>
                            <td  colspan='1' style='width: 15%'>".price_format($item_price)."</td>";

                    $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty); //Multiply item quantity * price
                    $total = ($total + $subtotal); //Add up to total price
                }

                $grand_total = $total + $shipping_cost; //grand total

                foreach ($taxes as $key => $value) { //list and calculate all taxes in array
                    $tax_amount = round($total * ($value / 100));
                    $tax_item[$key] = $tax_amount;
                    $grand_total = $grand_total + $tax_amount;
                }

                foreach ($tax_item as $key => $value) { //taxes List
                    $list_tax .= $key . ' ' . $currency . sprintf("%01.2f", $value) . '<br />';
                }

                $shipping_cost = ($shipping_cost) ? 'Shipping Cost : ' . $currency . sprintf("%01.2f", $shipping_cost) . '<br />' : '';

                echo $cart_box;
            }
            ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php
    $fetch_shipping_price = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st_custom_price` WHERE `meta_key`='shipping'");
    $fetch_price = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_shipping_price);
    $shipping_price = $fetch_price['meta_price'];
    $product_total = $total_price + $total_cost_price + ($price_detail['ttl_price']*$price_detail['qty']);

    if($_SESSION['price_coupon_price']){
        $total_amount = $total_price + $total_cost_price + ($price_detail['ttl_price']*$price_detail['qty']) - $_SESSION['price_coupon_price'];
        $_SESSION['price_coupon_value'] = $_SESSION['price_coupon_price'];

    }elseif($_SESSION['price_coupon_percent']){
        $total_amount = $total_price + $total_cost_price + ($price_detail['ttl_price']*$price_detail['qty']);
        $percent_total =  ($_SESSION['price_coupon_percent'] / 100) * $total_amount;
        $_SESSION['price_coupon_value'] = $percent_total;
        $total_amount = $total_amount - $percent_total;
    }else{
        $total_amount = $total_price + $total_cost_price + ($price_detail['ttl_price']*$price_detail['qty']);
    }

    $ttl_ship = $total_amount + $shipping_price;

    setcookie('total_cost', $ttl_ship, time() + (86400 * 2), "/");
    setcookie('total_cost', $ttl_ship, time() + (86400 * 2), "/");
    ?>  
    <?php if(!empty($total_amount) || count($cart_custom) > 0){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" colspan="3" style="width: 85%;">Totaal</th>
                    <th data-field="id" colspan="1" style="width: 15%;"> <?php echo price_format($product_total); ?></th>
                </tr>
                <?php if($_SESSION['price_coupon_price'] || $_SESSION['price_coupon_percent']){

                    $discount_type = ($_SESSION['coupon_data']['coupon_type'] == "price" ? " €" : " percent ");
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" colspan="3" style="width: 85%;">
                        <input id='remove_coupon_btn' name='remove_coupon_btn' type='hidden' value='' />
                        Kortingscode <?php echo $_SESSION['coupon_data']['coupon_name']; ?><input name='remove_coupon_btn'  style="width: 18px; vertical-align:bottom" type='image' value='remove_coupon_btn' src='/image/recycle.jpg' alt='Remove coupon' onclick = "return setHidden('remove_coupon_btn');" />
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 15%;"><?php echo price_format($total_amount-$product_total); ?></th>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" colspan="3" style="width: 85%;">Verzendingskosten</th>
                    <th data-field="id" colspan="1" style="width: 15%;"> <?php echo price_format($shipping_price); ?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" colspan="3" style="width: 85%;">Te betalen</th>
                    <th data-field="id" colspan="1" style="width: 15%;"> <?php echo price_format($ttl_ship); ?></th>
                </tr>
             </table>
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        <div class="more-products-pagination" style="float: left; position: relative; left: -50%;">
            <div class="coupon_row" style="margin:5px 20px">
            <?php if($_SESSION['price_coupon_price'] || $_SESSION['price_coupon_percent']){ ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <ul>
                    <li>Kortingscode</li>
                    <li><input type="text" name="coupon_apply" value=""><input type="submit" name="apply_coupon_btn" value="Toepassen" class="add_to_cart_btn" style="border: 1px solid #fff; display: inline-block;float: right;"></li>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="pagination_btn pagination_btn_right">
                <input type="submit" class="add_to_cart_btn" value="Afrekenen" name="checkout_btn">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>  
        </form>
        <?php }else {
                echo "Geen producten in uw winkelwagen.";
            }?>
    </div>
</div>
<script language="javascript">
    function setHidden(whichButton)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(whichButton);
        element.value = whichButton;
        return true;
    }
</script>
<?php
    include_once("inc/footer.php");
?>

 <style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(253, 245, 208,0.6);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #C1C1C1;
    }

    th, td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
        color:#444;
    }
    td{

    }
    th {
        background-color: #BD3F6F;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>
```

When I then try to access the variable $_SESSION['coupon_data'] on a different page this does not work, it is empty.

I set the variable here in this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['apply_coupon_btn'])){
        $query_coupon = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `st_coupon` WHERE `coupon_code`='{$_POST['coupon_apply']}' AND `status`='1'");
        $fetch_coupon = mysqli_fetch_array($query_coupon);
        $message = "tmp2";
        if(isset($fetch_coupon)){
            $_SESSION['coupon_data'] = $fetch_coupon;
..
    }
```

And then I call the next page here:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkout_btn'])){
    if($_SESSION['USER_EMAIL']){
        header("location: afrekenen.php");
    }else{ 
        header("location: winkelwagen.php#login-modelbox");
    }
}
```

Even if I call the update of the cart items in this same page, the session variables disapear for some reason which I do not understand:

```
if(isset($_POST['update_cart']))
{
    echo "update cart";
    foreach($_POST['custom_qty_cart'] as $key=>$qtys){
        $cart_custom[$key]['price']['qty'] = $qtys;
    }
    setcookie('view_cart_custom_fab', json_encode($cart_custom), time() + (86400 * 2), "/");
    setcookie('custom_qty', $_POST['custom_qty'], time() + (86400 * 2), "/");

    $custom_total = $custom_total*$_POST['custom_qty'];
    setcookie('custom', $custom_total, time() + (86400 * 2), "/");
    foreach($_POST["qty"] as $key => $qty) { //Print each item, quantity and price.
       $id = $_POST["product_id"][$key];
       $_SESSION["products"][$id]["fabric_qty"] = $qty;
    }
    header("location: winkelwagen.php");
}
```

I am utterly baffled and hope someone can help me out.

Comment: when u start `$_SESSION` u must have `session_start();` on begging of every page that u want to use that session. U can check your started sessions with `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: I can confirm session_start() is present on all involved pages, this is not the problem.

Comment: issue resolved, turns out there was another call to session_start in one of the includes which was creating a separate session and hence not allowing the correct globalisation.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved, turns out there was another call to session_start in one of the includes which was creating a separate session and hence not allowing the correct globalisation.